# No Dolby Digital Signal via optical out

Tags: debian, audio

System:
Debian Stretch (freshly installed. No backported software so far)
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-8350K CPU @ 4.00GHz
RAM: 16GB DDR4
Mainboard: MSI Z370M Mortar Intel Z370

aplay -l says:

```
 **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
    card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
      Subdevices: 1/1
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
    card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC892 Digital [ALC892 Digital]
      Subdevices: 0/1
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
    card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
      Subdevices: 1/1
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
    card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
      Subdevices: 1/1
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
    card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
      Subdevices: 1/1
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I am using the on board soundcard and dont want to use the nvidia one.
Playback device is a AKG Hearo 999 which is connected via Toslink. Sound as such works but when play a video file with vlc or the on board player or play an official dolby digital video on Youtube the Hearo 999 claims it is only a regular signal and only gives mit Dolby ProLogic. Realtek firmware package is installed and its not the hardware since it works in windows.

Answer (score 0):

By default, media players decode ProLogic and other compressed formats, because unless you have a low-bandwidth connection like Toslink, compression is not needed (e.g. it works fine without compression in HDMI).

So you need to (1) tell the media player to not decode it, and (2) configure Pulseaudio and/or ALSA for digital passthrough. (I'd have to look up the details myself, but that should get you started).

It's also possible to add an extra audio sink that accepts 5.1 or similar, and *encodes* it into fly into ProLogic, so you can use your Toslink to transfer more than stereo. Obviously it's better to use already encoded ProLogic in available media if you have it, because the encoding is not trivial, and properly mastered media will have better quality (though real 5.1 is better). Again, I'd have to google for the details.